how to convert raw Eddy Current and Ultrasonic data in CSV files
I have NDT datasets that consist of eddy current testing (ECT) and ultrasonic testing data, and I want to feed both of these datasets into a neural network. The problem is that I can't convert them no matter what I try. EddyFi-Ectane equipment is used for ECT, hence the reason why I can only open the ECT data with Magnifi. There is a possibility to convert the ECT data to CSV files using the software, but that doesn't solve the problem since I want this process to be automated. For the ultrasonic acquisition, Olympus-Omniscan is used, and there I have the same problem; I couldn't find a way to automate the process of converting those files to CSV And the reason I want this process automated is because I have dozens upon dozens of datasets, making manual conversion for every file is extremely time-consuming.
The ECT data is stored in Magdata files and the ultrasonic data in OPD files.
I've reached out to individuals who have previously attempted to feed ECT data into a CNN, but the situation differs significantly because they acquired the dataset themselves using self-built equipment, whereas I only have access to raw data from a company.
I have also searched the internet for any solutions, but unfortunately, I haven't been able to find anything relevant to my specific situation.
